# DOMContentLoaded events stops getting triggered. Why?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

Well, I'm developing a firefox addon that reload a given set of url automatically with some modification. Its not possible to show the whole code. So, I've just copy paste the part of the code which is giving me the error.

The `DOMContentLoaded` event is suppose to be triggered everything a page is loaded, and it do it properly. The problem is that, if i open a new tab, then `DOMContentLoaded` event is not triggered in the old tab.

```
//Any code here runs only for the first time u start the browser
window.addEventListener("load", function() { myExtension.init(); }, false);

var myExtension = { 
init: function()    
{
            var appcontent = document.getElementById("appcontent");
            if(appcontent)
            appcontent.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", myExtension.onPageLoad, true);
},

onPageLoad: function(aEvent)
{

    var doc = aEvent.originalTarget; // doc is document triggered "onload" event
    //execute on one the top page (not on iframes)
        if ((aEvent.originalTarget.nodeName == '#document') && (aEvent.originalTarget.defaultView.location.href == gBrowser.currentURI.spec)) 
        {setTimeout(function(){showInError(doc.location='about:home'}, 500);}  
},
}
```

I'd like to write the problem in a simple way (sorry for my bad English)

1) i run firefox, and the tab (say tab no.1) is continuously reloaded as i want.

2) the tab no.1 page continues to load repeatedly if i leave the page uninterrupted(that's what it want)

3) if i open a new tab (say tab no. 2), the new tab (tab no. 2) begins to reload continuously as i wanted. However, the tab no. 1 stops reloading.

what i want is to to keep on reloading both tab no 1 and tab no. 2. How to do it? what is wrong is my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are executing the script only on currently displayed page (active tab).

If you want to execute it on other tabs, you should attach event listeners to new tabs as you open them (and don't forget to remove them when you close the tab). You can get useful snippets for this functionality at this page:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL_School/Intercepting_Page_Loads#WebProgressListeners

Answer (score 0):

Try using gBrowser instead of document.getElementById("appcontent");

```
gBrowser.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", myExtension.onPageLoad, true);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/On_page_load#Basic_onPageLoad_for_a_browser_window